# Calculate the shortest way to rotate, right or left?

Tags: javascript

Im making a simple computerplayer to my simple 2d action game. it suppose to turn towards me and shoot, but i cant figure out how to calc the shortest path... should it turn left of right if it want to shoot and kill me :P ?

Ive got two angles: cpu_facing (direction the cpu is facing) and player_degree (the angle calculated when cpu is in the center).

(im working with degrees, dont like radian :P)

Anyone done this in javascript?

Comment: When they are directly facing each other, what is player_degree?

Comment: "the angle calculated when the CPU is in the center" center of what?
Do you have vectors of where the units are located?

Comment: "the angle calculated when cpu is in the center" center of what?

Comment: I would assume that "CPU is in the center" when calculating the angle to the player means that the CPU location is where the X and Y axes meet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
(cpu_facing-player_degree+360)%360>180
```

- `false`: turn in the negative direction
- `true`: turn in the positive direction

Comment: It would seem that this will always work, if `cpu_facing` is the current heading/facing direction, and if `player_degree` is the heading/direction the `cpu` is required to point at, in order to point at the `player`. If both of these items are true, then it'll always work, regardless of location.

Comment: wouldnt this do also: if( abs(cpu_facing-player_degree)<180 ) turn left else turn right?

Comment: @Jason94 no, as abs() will ignore a difference between, for example, `+5` and `-5`, but this means different directions.