# Efficiently calculate angle (and direction) between 3 points

Tags: javascript, optimization, language-agnostic

Using this thread ([Calculate the shortest way to rotate, right or left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370746/calculate-the-shortest-way-to-rotate-right-or-left))  I created a function that returns a positive or negative rotation angle.  Problem is, it seems really inefficient.  Can anyone help?  (for clarity purposes, i've spelled out the var names and created helper functions.)

```
function getRotation(center, target, heading) {

var north = new point(center.x(), center.y() + 10);

/*  I tried to calculate these seperately so I dont have to calc the distance so many tiems but couldnt come up with anything...
var distCenterToHeading = getDist(center, heading);
var distCenterToTarget = getDist(center, target);
var distTargetToHeading = getDist(target, heading);

var distCenterToNorth = 10;
var distNorthToHeading = getDist(north, heading);
var distNorthToTarget = getDist(north, target);
*/

var angHeadingToTarget = getAngle(center, heading, target);
var angNorthToHeading = getAngle(center, north, heading);
var angNorthToTarget = getAngle(center, north, target);



if (((angNorthToHeading - angNorthToTarget) + 360) % 360 > 180) {
    return angHeadingToTarget;
} else {
    return -angHeadingToTarget;
}
}

function getAngle(Center, heading, target) {
var p12 = getDist(Center, heading);
var p13 = getDist(Center, target);
var p23 = getDist(heading, target);

return Math.acos((sq(p12) + sq(p13) - sq(p23)) / (2 * p12 * p13)) * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function point(iX, iY) {
var _X=iX;
var _Y=iY;
this.x = function () { return _X; };
this.y = function () { return _Y; };

this.setX = function (iX) {
    _X = iX;
}
this.setY = function (iY) {
    _Y = iY;
}
}

function getDist(p1, p2) { return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x() - p2.x(), 2) + Math.pow(p1.y() - p2.y(), 2)); }

function sq(num) { return Math.pow(num, 2); }
```

I will potentially need to get the rotation many times, and i've heard that the sqrt function is expensive...  In the above example, it's being hit 9 times, where I can see that at least three of them are redundant (center to heading, center to target and center to north).

Is there a better way of doing this all-together?
Thanks in advance,
Dave

EDIT:  @Mike Dunlavey
I've been messing around with atan2 but I cant seem to get anything that works.  Maybe i'm just missing something simple, but could you explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) In your `getDist` function, it might be faster to just square the deltas, rather than calling `Math.pow`.
It's possible `Math.pow` treats integer powers as a special case, but in general it has to get wrapped up in `log` and `exp`, which you don't need.

2) To get the direction from one point to another, you can just use the `Math.atan2` function.
No need to deal with distances.