# Position search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I want to be able to position a drum in a certain location, but it might be better if I use an amusement park Ferris wheel as an example. I’m sure this search method has a name?

A Ferris wheel with 100 chairs is rotating and it randomly comes to a stop and chair number 90 is at the bottom and all passengers get out. Now if I want to bring chair number 10 to the ground so the passengers at chair 10 can get out, is there an algorithm that will help me calculate the shortest distance to chair number 10 that will rotate the Ferris wheel in the correct direction with least amount of counts to reach chair 10?

Comment: What do you mean by shortest distance?

Comment: correct direction ? it s only one direction ! is nt ?

Comment: Please provide more details about the data structures used.

Comment: Give us an example input and desired output of this algorithm

Comment: Sounds like a similar problem to this: http://www.heronomics.com/post/rotating-toward-closest-angle-or-direction/ [*EDIT*]or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370746/calculate-the-shortest-way-to-rotate-right-or-left

Comment: You should tell us where you would need this solution

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that chairs are numbered clockwise, and `N` is the number of chairs *(**100** in your example)*.

Also, let `stopped` be the number of the chair, where wheel stopped.

And `desired` is the number of the chair you want to reach.

So, algorithm will look as follow:

```
int distClockwise = desired - stopped;
if(distClockwise < 0) {
    distClockwise += N;
}

int distCounterClockwise = N - distClockwise;

if(distClockwise < distCounterClockwise) {
    //spin the wheel clockwise
}
else {
    //spin the wheel counterclockwise   
}
```

Comment: This code pretty much documents itself, but to make it painfully clear: the idea here is to compute how far both directions would need to get to the desired chair and then select the shortest direction.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and links.
GoogleHireMe, your correct, as Kaganar wrote, “the idea here is to compute how far both directions would need to get to the desired chair and then select the shortest direction”. As it’s written, your code won’t work for all possible positions, it seems to get the distance correct,(how many chairs it needs to move), but not direction.

Comment: has anyone worked out the maths equation that will do this for all combinations? I'm sort of there, but struggling.

Comment: @martin it's correct, and Kaganar didn't say nothing about the incorrectness - he just add some details to my answer (which are quite obvious due to variable names).

Comment: @martin Also, if you know (calculated with the equation above) that distClockwise (a number of chair to be moved clockwise to reach our desired destination) is larger than distance counterClockwise (`distCounterClockwise` in the code above), then, obviously, you should spin the wheel counterclockwise, and vice versa.

Comment: ok, thanks, how do you calculate how many chairs you need to move to get to the new location?

Comment: @martin if we are moving clockwise the answer will be `desired - stopped`. If `desired < stopped` we will receive the negative value (and this mean that we should reach the last chair (Nth) and then move from first to desired. What we actually need is to calculate `N - desired + stopped` where `N-desired` is the distance to the last chair, and `stopped` - a distance from first chair to the last one. On the other hand, the distance counterclockwise will be `N - distance clockwise` as we will pass by every chair only and exactly once spinning the wheel clockwise and counterclockwise.

Comment: I think maybe you can test your theory for all combinations

Comment: @martin well, I'm not interested. Maybe YOU want to show me example when this answer is wrong?